# How do I override fluentvalidator extension methods?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, overriding, fluentvalidation

I am using .NET ASP.NET MVC 4. For validation I am using Fluent validation. I am new to this. How can I override a method of the **DefaultValidatorExtensions** class?

I found one solution.

Create **basevalidator** class which inherited both **IValidatorInterceptor** and **AbstractValidator**. But I am not getting how to override validation methods.

Actually I want to change the default message of any validation method. The message is common for all attributes for some validations, so I want to override those validation methods rather to use 'WithMessage()'.

For example:

`RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();` will return " 'Name' should not be empty." But I want message 'Required'.

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer on this link. I think it can help you:
https://fluentvalidation.net/localization#default-messages

If you want to replace all (or some) of FluentValidation’s default messages then you can do this by implementing a custom version of the ILanguageManager interface.

For example, the default message for the NotNull validator is '{PropertyName}' must not be empty. If you wanted to replace this message for all uses of the NotNull validator in your application, you could write a custom Language Manager:

```
public class CustomLanguageManager : FluentValidation.Resources.LanguageManager {
  public CustomLanguageManager() {
    AddTranslation("en", "NotNullValidator", "'{PropertyName}' is required.");
  }
}
```

Here we have a custom class that inherits from the base LanguageManager. In its constructor we call the AddTranslation method passing in the language we’re using, the name of the validator we want to override, and the new message.

Once this is done, we can replace the default LanguageManager by setting the LanaguageManager property in the static ValidatorOptions class during your application’s startup routine:

```
ValidatorOptions.LanguageManager = new CustomLanguageManager();
```

This is a simple example that only replaces one validator’s message in English only, but could be extended to replace the messages for all languages. Instead of inheriting from the default LanguageManager, you could also implement the ILanguageManager interface directly if you want to load the messages from a completely different location other than the FluentValidation default (for example, if you wanted to store FluentValidation’s default messages in a database).

Of course, if all you want to do is replace this message for a single use of a validator, then you could just use WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' is required");